# Output Country Code to console

Tags: javascript, php

Hi I am trying to output country code to console or pass through javascript so I can do some conditional formatting. heres my code:

```
<?php
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}"));
  echo("<script>console.log('PHP: ".json_encode($details->country)."');
  </script>");
?>
```

My output in the console is `PHP: null`

**UPDATE**

To explain my objective:
I have a wp site which is being blocked in China. I have several services which I believe is issue including:

- Google Analytics
- Google recaptcha
- Google Maps
- Google Fonts
- Vimeo

I am wanting to detect country code then if its china then do not display scripts/css in php server side.

Thanks,

Comment: what's the result of `file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}")` possibly not what you are expecting (i.e. it's probably HTML)

Comment: I have just echo $details and output is `PHP: {"ip":"192.xxx.xx.x","bogon":true}`

Comment: seems you should be using `file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/$ip/json")` if you want JSON response - not even sure what those `{}` are for

Comment: yeah, I didn't ask what `$details` is, did I, I asked what `file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}")` is (before you attempted to json_decode non json)

Answer (score 0):

How about a jQuery version of what you are trying to do. 
It is a lot easier than the PHP version in my opinion.

```js
$.getJSON("https://ipinfo.io/",
    function(data){
      
       // show all options from data object
       //console.log(data);
       
       var country = data.country;
       var city = data.city;
       var loc = data.loc;
       var ip = data.ip
       
       var details = "<h1>"+ip+"</h1>"+"<br>COUNTRY: "+country+"<br>CITY: "+city+"<br>LOC: "+loc;
       
       $("#details").html(details);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="details"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code so far. (You can check with a hard-coded IP address ex. `8.8.8.8`)

You are testing your code under localhost, so `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` returns the local IP Address instead of the public IP.

The site `ipinfo.io` will not work with local IP Addresses, so it will response something like `{"ip":"192.xxx.xx.x","bogon":true}`. So there is no property named `country` in the response, which means `null`.

If you deploy your code to a "real" server (which has a public IP address) then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use ipinfo.io's official PHP client library: https://github.com/DavidePastore/ipinfo

```
<?php   
    // Initialize ipinfo 
    $ipInfo = new DavidePastore\Ipinfo\Ipinfo(array(
        "token" => "your_api_key" 
    ));

    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    //Get all the properties
    $host = $ipInfo->getFullIpDetails($ip);

    // Output Country to JavaScript Console
    echo("<script>console.log('PHP: ".$host->getCountry()."');</script>");
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove the curly brackets from the URL.

```
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/$ip"));
```

Comment: No problem with curly braces.